# Aliquot Sequence in Java

Tags: math, methods, return

I have just finished coding Aliquot Sequence. There is one problem that I am aware of and that is in the output it is always printing the original number because of the "return n" statement from static methods. How to use static method but not to print return n number? is it possible at all or should it be changed to static void?. Also, I would like to see possible shorter version of this program, maybe using another methods. Thank you.
          public class AliquotSequence {
          private static int divisors;

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(aliquotCheckOne(74));
    System.out.println(aliquotCheckTwo(AliquotSequence.divisors));
    System.out.println(aliquotCheckThree(AliquotSequence.divisors));
    System.out.println(finalCheck(AliquotSequence.divisors));
}

public static int aliquotCheckOne(int n1) {

    System.out.println("Divisors for number 74 are: ");
    for (int i = 1; i < n1; i++) {
        if (n1 % i == 0) {
            divisors += i;
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of divisors of number 74 is: " +       AliquotSequence.divisors);
    return n1;
}

public static int aliquotCheckTwo(int n2) {
    AliquotSequence.divisors = 0;
    System.out.println("Divisors for number 40 are: ");
    for (int i = 1; i < n2; i++) {
        if (n2 % i == 0) {
            divisors += i;
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of divisors of number 40 is: " + AliquotSequence.divisors);
    return n2;
}

public static int aliquotCheckThree(int n3) {
    AliquotSequence.divisors = 0;
    System.out.println("Divisors for number 50 are: ");
    for (int i = 1; i < n3; i++) {
        if (n3 % i == 0) {
            divisors += i;
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of divisors of number 50 is: " +   AliquotSequence.divisors);
    return n3;
}

public static int finalCheck(int n4) {
    AliquotSequence.divisors = 0;
    System.out.println("Divisors for number 43 are: ");
    for (int i = 1; i < n4; i++) {
        if (n4 % i == 0) {
            divisors += i;
            System.out.println(i);

        }

    }
    if (AliquotSequence.divisors == 1) {
        System.out.println("End of Aliquot Sequence");
    }
    return n4;
}
}

The output is:
Divisors for number 74 are: 
1
2
37
Sum of divisors of number 74 is: 40
74   (Here it prints return n)
Divisors for number 40 are: 
1
2
4
5
8
10
20
Sum of divisors of number 40 is: 50
40 (And again)
Divisors for number 50 are: 
1
2
5
10
25
Sum of divisors of number 50 is: 43
50 (again)
Divisors for number 43 are: 
1
End of Aliquot Sequence
43 (again)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to print the number in you're method parameters (for example `n1`) you can just make the method(s) void and remove return statement. If you want a way of printing the Aliquot Sequence...

```
int divisors(int n){
    if(n==1) return 0;
    int sum = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            sum += i;
            int d = n/i;
            if(d != i) {
                sum+=d;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

// use this 
void sequence(int n){
    System.out.println(n);
    int div = divisors(n);
    while(div>0) {
        System.out.println(div);
        div = divisors(div);
    }
    System.out.println(div);
}
```